# JavaFX scale components to fit parent without binding?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX application which will have user definable number of components and I am looking for easy way to scale all groups so that no matter of the number everything will fit:

For example I have a Pane, than in the pane I might have > 0 number of groups of components. Each group consists of several TilePanes and each of those TilePanes can accommodate other components.

I would like to be able to create any number of groups (same structure) as described so that when the number of groups increases the components in the group will decrease size to fit in the Pane. The difficulty is that while the program runs it will be adding components in the TilePanes of each group and those components need to be resized properly to fit.
Currently I have the sizes hard coded, but as explained I need to create configurable number of groups (set on initializations).
Is there an easy way to get this done without having to bind all the elements to the size of their parent ? I thought TilePane will restrict the size of the elements inside, but as it turned out, even when I set the max size for the TilePanes, large components don't get resized.

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing you need to look at FlowPane?

Comment: FlowPane wraps the elements when you resize the parent, but it is not resizing the elements which is what I am trying to achieve. The size of the GUI will stay the same, however when I add more groups I want to get everything scaled down

Comment: If this works for you, post your solution just in case this link goes down. https://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/javafx-1-3-growing-shrinking-and-filling/